# How to open file with .ltc extension

Tags: windows

How to open file with .ltc extension

This file is part of Football Manager 2013.
It is language file.

I want open it to fix some typo bugs.

Answer (score 1):

if this is not a binary file, you should be able to open it with notepad/wordpad/notepad++. If it is a binary file, then you cannot edit it. Try opening with notepad, if it is in human readable form, create a backup and try editing it.